# How do I declare a `type` key on a polymorphic relationship in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn ember.js and I have a problem with trying to use the `DS.FixtureAdapter` with mock data. Whenever I try to access the store I get an Ember error of:

*Error while processing route: exercises Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `pictureExercises` relationship instead it found an object. If this is a polymorphic relationship please specify a `type` key. If this is an embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin*` and specify the `pictureExercises` property in your serializer's attrs hash.*

Looking at the ember data section in the ember inspector I can see all the top level exercise data is loaded correctly, the PictureExercises and VideoExercises are not.

How do I declare a `type` key on a polymorphic relationship in Ember.js?

I'm at a total loss and any help would be greatly appreciated. **Thanks for your time.**

```
//Create application store    
Gymbo.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

//Set up models and relationships
    Gymbo.Exercise = DS.Model.extend({
        //id: DS.attr("number"), /*Ember will error if id is in model* /
        name: DS.attr("string"),
        description: DS.attr("string"),        
        pictureExercises: DS.hasMany("pictureExercise", {async: true }),
        videoExercises: DS.hasMany("videoExercise", { async: true }) 
    });


Gymbo.PictureExercise = DS.Model.extend({
        //id: DS.attr("number"),
        exerciseId: DS.attr("number"),       
        mimeType: DS.attr("string"),
        picFilePath: DS.attr("string"),
        picName: DS.attr("string"),
        exercise: DS.belongsTo("exercise")
    });

    Gymbo.VideoExercise = DS.Model.extend({
        //id: DS.attr("number"),
        exerciseId: DS.attr("number"),       
        videoName: DS.attr("string"),
        videoFilePath: DS.attr("string"),
        videoType: DS.attr("string"),
        exercise: DS.belongsTo("exercise")
    });

//UsersRoute
    Gymbo.ExercisesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return this.store.find("exercise");                      
        }
    });

//MOCK DATA
    Gymbo.Exercise.reopenClass({
        FIXTURES:
          [
            {
                "id": 101,
                "name": "Exercise 1",
                "description": "Description here",
                "pictureExercises": [
                    {
                        "id": 106,
                        "exerciseId": 101,                        
                        "mimeType": "PNG",
                        "picFilePath": "images\\strength",
                        "picName": "s001"                        
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 107,
                        "exerciseId": 101,                       
                        "mimeType": "JPG",
                        "picFilePath": "images\\strength",
                        "picName": s002
                    }
                ],
                "videoExercises": [
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "exerciseId": 101,                       
                        "videoName": "Test",
                        "videoFilePath": "Video\\strength",
                        "videoType": "mp4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
        "id": 102,
                //Data removed for brevity.....
            }
          ]
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the async flags on the hasMany relationships? Those are telling the adapter to expect ids instead of objects in the Exercise records. The adapter would then go make a separate request for those records based on their ids. This might not intuitively make a lot of sense for a FixtureAdapter but it makes a lot of sense if these are big records being served up from a remote API.

Comment: Yeah I have tried removing them but to no avail, I get the same error. I was hoping to build a mock site using FIXTURES and then simply swap out to a RESTAdapter. I'm thinking I'll give this a go now anyway and see if it makes a difference, I have lost a lot of time. I will post here if I get an answer or some working code. Thanks for your input though, most kind.

Comment: Have you found the solution? The other thing I would think of is setting coalesceFindRequests to true in the adapter.

Comment: Hi, not found the solution. Dev manager is about to pull the plug on Ember. His reasoning is its not fit for production as Emberdata seems flaky, there is not much support and its an unproven product. I can sort of agree, he can't take the chance especially as we have angular skills in team. I had a day to produce a reasonable mock up but have failed. I will, if I have the time, continue this on my own. Thanks so much for making the effort to contribute, your last suggestion didn't work either. I wish you luck if you use emberdata, I've really liked using ember. Will post if I find answer .